# For loop with asterisk symbol

Tags: java, for-loop

I need the output to be the asterisk symbol to print out one more each time it prints.

Like so

```
*
**
***
****
```

and so on.

This is what I have so far...

```
       String asterisk = ‘*’;
       int i;

       for(i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
       i = asterisk +1;
       System.out.println(i);
       }
```

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what the line `i = asterisk +1;` does? ([Rubber duck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging))

Comment: @esqew - Thanks for sharing this link ([Rubber duck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). I learnt about a new technique today.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need this code:

```
String asterisk = "";

for(int i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
   System.out.println(asterisk);
   asterisk +="*";
}
```

Comment: You where faster :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want do with `i = asterisk + 1`?

I guess that you have this two options:

```
   String asterisk = "*";
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      asterisk += "*";
      System.out.println(asterisk);
   }
```

That way you are increasing the string any time in the `for` loop

```
   String asterisk = "*";
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
          System.out.print(asterisk);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
```

That way you are printing the asterisk `i` times any loop in the `for` loop